# Adding to list, Haskell compiling error

Tags: haskell

```
-- Sample test data

type Sales = (String, String, Int)


testData :: [Sales]

testData :: [("Me and My Broken Heart","Rixton"),("It’s My Birthday","will.i.am"),("Problem","Ariana Grande")]


-- record a sale of a track 

sellTrack :: String String-> [Sales]

sellTrack :: trackName artistName = [Sales] ++ [(trackName, artistName, numberSold)]
```

I get the error "illegal literal in type : "Me and my broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `=` in the definition:

```
testData :: [Sales]

testData = [("Me and My Broken Heart","Rixton",5),("It’s My Birthday","will.i.am",4),("Problem","Ariana Grande",3)]
```